Docker build issue with platform
1 warning found (use docker --debug to expand):
- InvalidBaseImagePlatform: Base image public.ecr.aws/lambda/go:1.2024.10.04.19 was pulled with platform "linux/amd64", expected "linux/arm64" for current build (line 19)
Docker file:
# Builder stage
FROM golang:1.22-bookworm AS builder

# Copy the Go module files and download dependencies
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
ENV GOPROXY=http://athens-v2.ktp.io
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source code
COPY . /go/src/github.com/kna-core/atom-itempoolsync-lambda
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/kna-core/atom-itempoolsync-lambda

# Build the code 
ENV GOPROXY=http://athens-v2.ktp.io
RUN go mod download
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o ./main-handler -v 

# Runtime stage
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/go:1.2024.10.04.19

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/kna-core/atom-itempoolsync-lambda/main-handler 
${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/main-handler

CMD ["main-handler"]

Docker issue with build command:(I am facing below issue with docker image with arm64=> how to resolve this issue?)
docker build --platform linux/arm64 --progress=plain -t itempoolsync-lambda . 
        #0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

        #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
        #1 transferring dockerfile: 769B done
        #1 DONE 0.0s

        #2 [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/go:1.2024.10.04.19
        #2 ...

        #3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.22-bookworm
        #3 DONE 1.9s

        #2 [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/go:1.2024.10.04.19
        #2 DONE 2.0s

        #4 [internal] load .dockerignore
        #4 transferring context: 56B done
        #4 DONE 0.0s

        #5 [builder 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.22-bookworm@sha256:0d22c0d84536a5bb9bdd5b65b71fad5df32e648b2dfd10cb3fd87e4063da0f9c
        #5 DONE 0.0s

        #6 [internal] load build context
        #6 transferring context: 296B 0.0s done
        #6 DONE 0.0s

        #7 [stage-1 1/3] FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/go:1.2024.10.04.19@sha256:b4b00b112aeae7fe81b70c308374b342125a96a9ca2a916f38dd1f8bb737378f
        #7 resolve public.ecr.aws/lambda/go:1.2024.10.04.19@sha256:b4b00b112aeae7fe81b70c308374b342125a96a9ca2a916f38dd1f8bb737378f 0.0s done
        #7 DONE 0.0s

        #8 [builder 2/7] COPY go.mod go.sum ./
        #8 CACHED

        #9 [builder 3/7] RUN go mod download
        #9 0.627 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
        #9 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c go mod download" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
        ------
        > [builder 3/7] RUN go mod download:
        0.627 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
        ------

        1 warning found (use docker --debug to expand):
        - InvalidBaseImagePlatform: Base image public.ecr.aws/lambda/go:1.2024.10.04.19 was pulled with platform "linux/amd64", expected "linux/arm64" for current build (line 19)
        Dockerfile:7
        --------------------
           5 |     COPY go.mod go.sum ./
           6 |     ENV GOPROXY=http://athens-v2.ktp.io
           7 | >>> RUN go mod download
           8 |     
           9 |     # Copy the source code
        --------------------
        ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c go mod download" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


The warning is a red herring. Your real problem is that your go mod download in your builder failed. At a guess, I think you need to pin your builder to your native platform as docker is unable to emulate arm64 well enough for it. eg. FROM --platform=linux/amd64 golang:1.22-bookworm AS builder.
